# How to fix div on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you scroll down the page in the following URL, the 'share' div will lock onto the browser:

http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/pizza-is-a-vegetable

I'm assuming they are applying a `position: fixed;` attribute. How can this be achieved with jQuery?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You can find an example below. Basically you attach a function to `window`'s `scroll` event and trace `scrollTop` property and if it's higher than desired threshold you apply `position: fixed` and some other css properties.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function fix_element() {
    $('#target').css(
      $(window).scrollTop() > 100
        ? { 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '10px' }
        : { 'position': 'relative', 'top': 'auto' }
    );
    return fix_element;
  }());
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
code {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #efefef;
}
#target {
  color: #c00;
  font: 15px arial;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #c00;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">This <code>div</code> is going to be fixed</div>
```

Comment: @Emre - What if i use `$(window).scroll(fixDiv).resize(fixDiv);` instead of `$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
  fixDiv();`

Answer (score 15):

On jQuery for designers there's a well written post about this, this is the jQuery snippet that does the magic. just replace #comment with the selector of the div that you want to float.

**Note:** To see the whole article go here: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $obj = $('#comment');
  var top = $obj.offset().top - parseFloat($obj.css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));

  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= top) {
      // if so, ad the fixed class
      $obj.addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      // otherwise remove it
      $obj.removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: works great when you change the var name "top" to another name, but it's kinda anoying to replace all the #comment, you should use an object for that.

Answer (score 11):

I made a mix of the answers here, took the code of @Julian and ideas from the others, seems clearer to me, this is what's left:

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wq2Ej/) http://jsfiddle.net/wq2Ej/

## jquery

```
//store the element
var $cache = $('.my-sticky-element');

//store the initial position of the element
var vTop = $cache.offset().top - parseFloat($cache.css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= vTop) {
      // if so, ad the fixed class
      $cache.addClass('stuck');
    } else {
      // otherwise remove it
      $cache.removeClass('stuck');
    }
  });
```

## css:

```
.my-sticky-element.stuck {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(function($) {
  var triggers = [];
  $.fn.floatingFixed = function(options) {
    options = $.extend({}, $.floatingFixed.defaults, options);
    var r = $(this).each(function() {
      var $this = $(this), pos = $this.position();
      pos.position = $this.css("position");
      $this.data("floatingFixedOrig", pos);
      $this.data("floatingFixedOptions", options);
      triggers.push($this);
    });
    windowScroll();
    return r;
  };

  $.floatingFixed = $.fn.floatingFixed;
  $.floatingFixed.defaults = {
    padding: 0
  };

  var $window = $(window);
  var windowScroll = function() {
    if(triggers.length === 0) { return; }
    var scrollY = $window.scrollTop();
    for(var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
      var t = triggers[i], opt = t.data("floatingFixedOptions");
      if(!t.data("isFloating")) {
        var off = t.offset();
        t.data("floatingFixedTop", off.top);
        t.data("floatingFixedLeft", off.left);
      }
      var top = top = t.data("floatingFixedTop");
      if(top < scrollY + opt.padding && !t.data("isFloating")) {
        t.css({position: 'fixed', top: opt.padding, left: t.data("floatingFixedLeft"), width: t.width() }).data("isFloating", true);
      } else if(top >= scrollY + opt.padding && t.data("isFloating")) {
        var pos = t.data("floatingFixedOrig");
        t.css(pos).data("isFloating", false);
      }
    }
  };

  $window.scroll(windowScroll).resize(windowScroll);
})(jQuery);
```

and then make any div as floating fixed by calling

```
$('#id of the div').floatingFixed();
```

source: https://github.com/cheald/floatingFixed