# How to make a floating block menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, floating

For my new website I'm looking for a module, code snippet or whatever, to make a fixed menu appear at the top of a page once someone reaches the bottom of the sidebar.

[image: illustration floating menu]

Comment: provide your source code.

Comment: That should be simple by comparing the bottom of your lowest side bar item, to scrollTop and then changing the css of the menu to `position: fixed`, however, that's going to look really funny scrolling up and down. Who on earth would want such a weird site. I can't even picture how that's going to be "user friendly"

Answer (score 0):

You could try [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644248/jquery-fix-div-when-browser-scrolls-to-it), judging from the JS Fiddle it looks like it's doing what you want.

EDIT:

I really should have put this 'answer' as a comment. My apologies.