# Fix a div after scrolling in mobile browsers

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to fix a div during scrolling of the page. My code works in desktop browsers but it is not working in mobile devices where the div is fixed only when the scroll bar stops.
You can test the page here www.spiaggiati.it/antani/.

The code is:

```
function fixDiv() {
var $div = $("#order");
if ($(window).scrollTop() > $div.data("top")) {
    $div.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '-10px', 'width': $('div#content').width()});
    $('#categories').css('margin-top', '50px');
}
else {
    $div.css({'position': 'static', 'top': 'auto'});
    $('#categories').css('margin-top', '0px');
}
}
```

Comment: 30 euro per un minestrone? O_O

Comment: This might be something you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644248/jquery-fix-div-when-browser-scrolls-to-it

Comment: Samuele, è una pagina di prova. C'è anche la pizza bianca a 23,30 € se ti interessa :p

Answer (score 0):

I assume `fixDiv()` is fired constantly using the `scroll`-event.

If so then there's no solution at the moment as this is how scrolling on mobile devices works. The `scroll` event is triggered only when the scrolling has come to an end. As long as the momentum is moving the content *no* events are fired at all. You can see this in [Figure 6-1 The panning gesture](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) in Apple's "*Safari Web Content Guide*".

Comment: yes, this is the trigger: $(window).scroll(fixDiv). So there is no solution at the moment? :(

Comment: @user737024 I'm afraid there isn't. :-/