# How to freeze div when scroll to check the inner div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I scroll the div `#3` to look for it inner div, I want to freeze the div id 2... How do I do it?

```
<div id='1' style="height:15%; border:1px solid black">Questions</div>
<div id='2' style="height:30%; border:1px solid black">Freeze this</div>
<div id='3' style="height:55%; border:1px solid black">Scroll this
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
  <div class='innerDiv' style="border:1px solid black;height:50px">a</div>
</div>
```

How to freeze the  when scroll to check the inner div of

Comment: Check [jQuery: Fix div when browser scrolls to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644248/jquery-fix-div-when-browser-scrolls-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

With CSS:

```
#3 { overflow:scroll; }
```

You'll have to change the ID to a valid one, but that should do the trick.