# Div with fixed position in a scrollable modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div in a modal with scroll that should have fixed position relative to the browser window, and should not scroll away with the modal.

I tried `position:fixed`, but it doesn't work. Here you can see issue in it's context:

```js
$('.launchConfirm').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#confirm').modal({
        show: true
    });
});
```

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="container">
        <br />
        <button type="button" class="btn launchConfirm">Open modal</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <div style="position:fixed;top:40px;left:10px;background-color:red">This div should be fixed<br>and should not scroll away.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                some random buttons
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

How could I fix that div?

Comment: @Dejan.S the fixed div will contain some buttons related to the form in the modal, which are right now at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue based on answers by @Shiplo Rahman and @Dejan.S

Removed the modal-header, put everything in modal-body and doing a jquery workaround described here: [jQuery: Fix div when browser scrolls to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644248/jquery-fix-div-when-browser-scrolls-to-it)

```js
$('.launchConfirm').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#confirm').modal({
        show: true
    });
});

jQuery(function($) {
  function fixDiv() {
    var $cache = $('#getFixed');
    if ($('.modal-body').scrollTop() > 50)
    {
    $cache.css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '0px',
        'left': '25px',
        'width': '600px'
      });
    }
    else
      $cache.css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'top': 'auto',
        'left': '10px'
      });
  }
  $('.modal-body').scroll(fixDiv);
  fixDiv();
});
```

```css
    @import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
.modal-open .modal {
   //overflow: hidden;
 }
 .modal-body {
   height: calc(100vh - 126px);
   overflow-y: scroll;
 }
 
 #getFixed {
   position: relative;
   left: 10px;
   width: 600px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="page-container">
    <div class="container">
        <br />
        <button type="button" class="btn launchConfirm">Open modal</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" id="confirm2">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                 <div id="getFixed" style="background-color:red">This div should be fixed<br>and should not scroll away.</div>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                some random buttons
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Here is the source:
http://jsfiddle.net/roahda03/21/

Answer (score 7):

You will need to move the DIV outside of the modal.

Fixed positioning works in relation to the `viewport` **except** when an ancestor element has a `transform` applied to it. `.modal-dialog` has `transform` applied to it which creates a new context in which to position the DIV (this is why your DIV stays inside of the modal).

[CSS Positioning - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: He is right. Try to place that DIV under the `<div class="modal-dialog>...</div>`. It should work.

Answer (score 4):

You can use like this.

```js
$('.launchConfirm').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#confirm').modal({
        show: true
    });
});
```

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
.modal-open .modal {
   overflow: hidden;
 }
 .modal-body {
   height: calc(100vh - 126px);
   overflow-y:scroll;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="container">
        <br />
        <button type="button" class="btn launchConfirm">Open modal</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <div style="position:fixed;top:40px;left:10px;background-color:red">This div should be fixed<br>and should not scroll away.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                some random buttons
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: I don't need the title to be fixed. Although, you gave me an idea and managed to solve the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

to have a fixed div in a modal, do this:

```
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog">

    <div class="fixed-div">
        *your fixed div here...
        it can even be your .modal-header div*
    </div>

    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
```

CSS:

```
.fixed-div {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1051; /* anything above 1050*/
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

`.fixed-div` can be your `.modal-header` as well;
but the `.modal-header` must be after `.modal` not after `.modal-content`

Comment: What's up with the 1050?

Comment: The `z-index` value of bootstrap modal is `1050`. If you want any element to stay visible on top of the modal, you gotta use `z-index` value above `1050`

Answer (score -1):

In the modal-body you should set a max-height and then tell to overflow so:

```
.modal-body{
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I don't want the title to be fixed, just the div.

Comment: ah ok, then you should place the div outside the modal or at least outsitde the .modal-content div