# position: sticky is not working on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-position, sticky

I have tried to set CSS property to a DIV: `position: sticky`
But it doesn't work for IE11 and Edge15, does anyone familiar with any CSS pure polyfill that I can use in order to overcome this issue on those browsers?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky

Comment: I know is it not supported I wanted to ask if there is a polyfill or a replacement for IE that I can use?

Comment: you need to share your code, we may find a woraround using other techniques ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644248/fix-div-when-browser-scrolls-to-it